# How should I secure NM wire that someone ran outside of two studs?

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]

This is behind a closet that we’re going to Sheetrock and finish. The wire runs through a hole in the corner, around two studs and into another corner. I’m thinking of notching the studs 1/4” so Sheetrock can go on. I’ll attach metal plates to protect those notches of course.

But what about the fact that the romex would run close along the back of the Sheetrock? Is that code complaint? I’m thinking of attaching a metal “shield” across from he studs against the drywall, or cut a PVC conduit to enclose the wire between studs. There is not much slack in the wire.

Any suggestions? I’d hate to cut the wire and run a splice across two junction boxes just so this can go through centrally drilled holes. Seems like overkill. Though, if that’s the only code compliant solution, I’ll do that.

Thanks!

Edited to add detail: Wire is 2' from concrete subfloor. Other side of OSB is drywall and an adjoining room. Additionally, I believe the OSB is a sheer wall, and would avoid cutting it, and can't see any reason I'd have to anyway. Studs are 2x6 and 90% sure they're load-bearing for a 2-story house, so I'd like to avoid cutting more than a small notch.

Comment: You can't cut and splice; you don't have enough slack.  Besides you would need an accessible junction box to be there permanently.

Comment: @Harper Well, OP is suggesting two junction boxes, so two splices and a longer replacement for the middle section. But it definitely seems like overkill to have two boxes like that.

Comment: What is the height of this cable above the floor? What is on the other side of the OSB on the other sides of the studs? Are those 2x4 or 2x6 studs? Is this a load bearing wall?

Comment: You could notch the studs deep to the center, place the wire in, and attach Simpson stud shoe. Drill 3/4" holes in the centers, cut through and place the wire, then attach a stud shoe, e.g., https://www.walmart.com/ip/SIMPSON-D-stud-studs-Strong-Gauge-tie-reinforce-Strong-tie-in-10-Simpson-SS1-5-12-16-Shoe-shoes-TIE-Galvanized-Stud-By-STRONG-Fasteners-notched-Stron/419111028? Could even fill the cut with a piece of wood glued in to resist compression, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: @JimStewart Cable is about 2' off the floor. Other side of OSB is sheetrock wall for adjoining room. The 2x6 studs are probably load-bearing, though I have not consulted a structural engineer. The studs extend from bottom plate up to top plate, which in turn has a 2x6 on the 2nd floor, directly to an attic joist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would put in two boxes and put a spliced wire through holes in the studs. Somebody, someday might drive nails or screws into that wall and you don't want to be the cause of their hitting a wire. It's a closet, who's going to care if there are covered boxes in the walls?

You could notch the studs deep to the center, place the wire in, and attach Simpson stud shoes. You'd drill 3/4" holes in the centers, cut through, place the wire, then attach a stud shoe, e.g., walmart.com/ip/…? Could even fill the cut with a piece of wood glued in to resist compression, but that's probably overkill. But how much work and expense is that compared to two boxes?!

Comment: I'm leaning towards reluctantly installing 2 j-boxes now, thanks. It seems the safest and most code compliant approach and avoids doing more than put two holes in those studs. I agree that the aesthetics of having two wall plates at this location are not an issue.

It's good to know stud shoes like that exist (makes sense). If used a deep notch, I'd definitely glue in a tight piece of wood + use Simpson. But I'd still be concerned whether that's a structurally sound approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Joe, the metal Simpson plates are for exactly that purpose put them on every 2x4 over the wire. Don't cut the wire or you'll have to add in a j-box, actually 2 of them.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid cutting and installing 2 j-boxes too. Perhaps it's possible to find a long Simpson plate that could span the length of the wire? I'd like to avoid cutting deep into these studs since they're almost certainly load-bearing (on a ground floor of a 2-story house - I'll add that detail in the original question). But it'd also like to avoid zapping someone in the future who unsuspectingly puts a blade into that wall.